# jQuery PUT ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, couchdb, backbone.js

I'm trying to save a Backbone model in couchdb so I've overridden the `save` method with a ajax requet to couchdb:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/movies/' + this.get('id'),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(this.toJSON()),
    success: function() {
      console.log('asdf');
    },
    failure: function() {
     console.log('test');
    }
  });
```

The request is sent but when I look at the couchdb log jQuery seems to send a `OPTIONS` HTTP method instead of `PUT`:

> [info] [<0.1601.0>] 127.0.0.1 - -
>   'OPTIONS' /movies/862 405

and couchdb sends a `405` HTTP Response code (method not allowed). Any Ideas?

**Edit**
Here are the headers sent to CouchDB:

```
OPTIONS /movies/862 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:8888
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
```

Comment: Where that 'this' is pointing to?

Comment: the backbone model, but that shouldn't have anything todo with the HTTP request method problem

Comment: Which version of jQuery? The AJAX portion was *completely* rewritten recently.

Comment: The latest version (Downloaded today)

Comment: Can you show us the entire custom `save` method you wrote? Is there anything else there other than what you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a backbone connector for couch-db.. https://github.com/janmonschke/backbone-couchdb

Answer (score 0):

PUT isn't supported by all browsers. Also, the property for your data is "data", not "body".

Comment: which browsers? I've tested it on Firefox 4, Chrome 11 and Safari 5

Comment: and why would it default to a hardly ever used HTTP method instead of throwing an error

Comment: Is it a CROSS-SITE request? Are you using that IP in the browser for the page you're viewing? If so that explains why the PUT is shifted to the access control method parameter and an OPTIONS request is generated.

Comment: it's running on localhost just on different ports would that matter?

Comment: and the way couchdb works (I think) it has to be running on diffrrent ports

Comment: To be considered a request to the same domain it must be the same protocol, domain name, and port. Testing confirms this.

Comment: Yes it is a cross domain request if the port changes. You need to specify the accept origin header in the server response. And it doesn't work in IE if you do not use JSONP