# Alternative headers to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

So I have a funny little problem.

When calling my `API` from an `AngularJS` client with the following code, everything works fine, except that my `API` only recieves an empty object as data:

```
var req = {
      method: 'Post',
      url: config.API + request.toLowerCase() + '/',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      data: data
}

 $http(req)
     .then(function(response){
          // handling response
     })
```

Now, if I remove the `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }` or changes it to `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` I get the this error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'

My `API` controller looks like this:

```
    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        Response response = new Response();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    }
```

What I'm looking for is a way to prevent the tiresome "OPTIONS not supported" error, and still be able to send dynamic data to my controller

**EDIT**
Regarding the duplicate, I've already tried their approach, hence why I already are using `[EnableCors]` in my controller. But if I add this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

I get this error instead

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
>   but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:82' is therefore not
>   allowed access

Comment: It seems it's trying to make an OPTIONS request for some reason. Can you try changing `method: 'Post'` to `method: 'POST'` (all caps) - just a guess, but perhaps it's case-sensitive.

Comment: OPTIONS is a preflight request made internally by the browser as part of CORS spec. Has nothing to do with your client side code. You need to make sure server accepts that method

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: Have you tried looking into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352519/the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http-method-options)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support HTTP OPTIONS verb in ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application)

Comment: @guest271314: `data` is a Javascript object which deferres from request to request

Comment: If `data` is a `javascript` object why do you set `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @guest271314: I did that as a result of a suggestion to an older problem. I would like to change the `Content-Type` but doing so gives me the mentioned error ;-)

Comment: Note, have not tried `angularjs` or `asp.net-web-api`. `string Post` appears at server, then `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);`? Should not the settings be consistent?

Comment: @vlaz: Changing `Post` to `POST` didn't change anything :-(

Comment: @guest271314: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);` returns a `string` :-)

Comment: To url encode a JavaScript object use the [AngularJS $httpParamSerializerJQLike Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike).